# deregistering kubernetes pods from Consul

Tags: c#, kubernetes, asp.net-core-3.1, consul

I am using a `IHostedService` to register my pods inside the k8s cluster. It all runs fine but when I need to update or scale my deployments I get zombie pods hanging around in Consul.

My `IHostedService` implements the `StopAsync` as follows:

```
public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
            _logger.LogInformation("De-registering from Consul");
            try
            {
                await _consulClient.Agent.ServiceDeregister(_registrationId, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"De-registration failed");
            }
        }
```

I also tried injecting in `IHostApplicationLifetime` and registering an `ApplicationStopping` but it's the same deal - these functions never get called unless I physically press ctrl +c which obviously isn't happening inside k8s

How is everyone deregistering their pods?

I'm using netcore 3.1

Comment: When you say zombie pods, can you explain? Can you post the output of `kubectl get pods`? It can be normal for a terminated position to hang around a little while before getting cleaned up.

Comment: So say they are being scaled to zero - the pods are removed from k8s but consul still thinks they are there - just not responding to health - because they never deregister - because StopAsync is never being called